# Will non-textual search benefit from search engine?

Tags: mysql, search, lucene, sphinx, faceted-search

I have a web-site with search. Running MySQL database. I wonder if it will benefit in performance from search engine (Sphinx, Lucene, etc.)? How, if it will? Can I make use of faceted search? I know it would benefit if there was text search. But could it benefit if most of queries are something like following.

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS distinct tableA.id
    from tableA as A
        join tableB as B1 on A.id=B1.tablea_id
        join tableB as B2 on A.id=B2.tablea_id
        join tableB as B3 on A.id=B3.tablea_id
where
    B1.value in ([list of ints here])
and
    B2.value in ([another list of ints here])
and
    B2.value in ([one more list of ints here])
order by ~A.updated_at
limit <from>,<amount>;
```

The idea is to look for rows in `tableA` having values in `tableB` from first list, then filter then to leave those having values in `tableB` from second list, etc. Sort them, count all found and limit.

`tableA` and `tableB` are like this:

```
create table tableA (
    id int(11) not null autoincrement,
    ...
    updated_at timestamp not null,
    primary key (`id`),
    key `ix_tablea_updated_at` (`updated_at`)
) engine=InnoDB;

create table tableB (
    tablea_id int(11) not null,
    value int(11) not null,
    key `ix_tableb_tablea_id` (`tablea_id`),
    key `ix_tableb_value` (`value`)
) engine=InnoDB;
```

`tableA` contains ~200k rows. `tableB` contains ~1.2M rows. Number of `B.value in ([list of ints])` differs from query to query, as do `lists of ints`.

If there is no way I can benefit from search engine, can I improve performance by any other means?

As far as I can say the problem is `order by ~A.updated_at` and counting found rows. Is there a way to speed up sorting and counting using MySQL itself?

PS. Excuse my English. Hope you will understand me.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you joining the table B three times on the same id?  You can get the same effect with one join:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS distinct tableA.id
from tableA A join
     tableB B
     on A.id = B.tablea_id
where B.value in ([list of ints here]) and
      B.value in ([another list of ints here]) and
      B.value in ([one more list of ints here])
order by A.updated_at
limit <from>, <amount>;
```

Having three lists is redundant, so you could also do:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS distinct tableA.id
from tableA A join
     tableB B
     on A.id = B.tablea_id
where B.value in ([big big combined list of ints here]) 
order by A.updated_at
limit <from>, <amount>;
```

If you have an index on `B(value)` or even `B(value, tablea_id)` then performance will be even better.

EDIT:

No, your query does not work the way you think it does.  Each time you join to the be table, you are multiplying the number of rows.  Say, the value QQQ in the A table has 10 corresponding rows in the B table.  The first join gets 10 rows, the second multiplies this to 100, and the third to 1,000.  This is probably the root of your performance problem.

You are just doing successive filtering on the same column.  Actually, I suspect that you really want to know all As where there is a B id in each of the three lists.  If so, then this is a "set-within-sets" query, and easily done using `group by`:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tableA.id
from tableA A join
     tableB B
     on A.id = B.tablea_id
group by tableA.id
having sum(B.value in ([list of ints here])) > 0 and
       sum(B.value in ([another list of ints here])) > 0 and
       sum(B.value in ([one more list of ints here])) > 0
order by A.updated_at
limit <from>, <amount>;
```

Your original approach probably does work -- which is interesting.  It would typically be quite inefficient (unless one of the values never appears in the data so the joins end up returning no rows).

Comment: If I will join `tableB` only once, then `B.value` should be in all 3 lists simultaneously. (Should not it?). And if I join it several times then I can filter A's to have B.values from first list and from second list and etc, separately. Am I wrong? It seems to work as I say. I do have `ix_tableb_value` index.

Comment: I am not filtering on the same column. If I have for some row in A (1,2,3) values from B, then joining B 3 times will give me [(1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,1,3),(1,2,1),..,(3,3,3)] and then I can find A where B1.value=1, B2.value=2, B3.value=3. Is that correct?

Comment: Using `group by` gives the same results, but it takes ~2 times longer to execute. Anyway, thanks for trying.

Comment: @zaquest . . . If you remove the "A" table (and the `order by` and change the `group by` to `tablea_id`), how long does the query with the `group by` take?

Comment: Query from my question takes 4-5s; from your answer 9-10s; `group by` without `order by` and without A takes 5-6s. If I remove `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `order by` they all return answer instantly (0.00s)

Comment: There is a case to be made that `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in itself is bad. You might find forming your request as two seperate queries, one to get the <amount> of actual rows, and a seperate one using a COUNT(...) to get the total number of rows.

Comment: @barryhunter Yes, I heard `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` could be slow. I tested it both ways with `count()` and with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. It makes no difference in my case. As long as one of `order by` or `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is present the query is slow. And actually `count()` and `order by` in separate queries takes twice as longer as `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `order by` do in a single query.